# When to use Include in EF? Not needed in projection?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following in Entity Framework Core:

```
public class Book {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }
}

public class Theme {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public Byte[] Illustration { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Ebook> Ebooks { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following linq query:

```
List<BookModel> books = await context.Books.Select(x =>
  new BookModel {
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    Theme = new ThemeModel {
      Id = x.Theme.Id,
      Name = x.Theme.Name
    }
   }).ToListAsync();
```

I didn't need to **include the Theme** to make this work, e.g:

```
List<BookModel> books = await context.Books.Include(x => x.Theme).Select(x => ...
```

When will I need to use Include in Entity Framework?

**UPDATE**

I added a column of type Byte[] Illustration in Theme. In my projection I am not including that column so will it be loaded if I use Include? Or is never loaded unless I have it in the projection?

Comment: Just use `await context.Books.Include(x => x.Theme).ToListAsync();` you'll get the same resultset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't need Include because you were working inside EF context. When you reference Theme inside the anonymous object you are creating, that's not using lazy loading, that's telling EF to do a join.

If you return a list of books and you don't include the themes, then when you try to get the theme you'll notice that it's null. If the EF connection is open and you have lazy loading, it will go to the DB and grab it for you. But, if the connection is not opened, then you have to get it explicitly.

On the other hand, if you use Include, you get the data right away. Under the hood it's gonna do a JOIN to the necessary table and get the data right there.

You can check the SQL query that EF is generating for you and that's gonna make things clearer for you. You'll see only one SQL query.

Comment: I am not using Lazy Loading as I using EF 7 which does not support Lazy Loading so what is the difference between using Include or not in my Code? Should I NOT use Include, for example, if one of the columns of that  child entity is to large and I do not needed it?

Comment: I didn't say you were getting the data using lazy loading. EF is generating only one SQL query for you. I said that EF is doing a join because you are referring a theme in the creation of the anonymous object. That's still before the SQL query is executed.

Comment: I added an update ... If a column of Theme is not in the Projection will it be loaded if I use Include? That is something I was afraid of.

Comment: It will only get the columns you need. The best way to check it is to the SQL query that EF generated for you. You can either use SQL Profiler or trace EF query in Visual Studio.

Comment: 1) Are you saying that `include` has a purpose only used with Lazy loading? 2) when .ToList() is called then it will fetch data from the db and convert into list. So what do you mean by return a list? Please can you give an example?

Answer (score 12):

In search for an official answer to your question from Microsoft's side, I found this quote from Diego Vega (part of the Entity Framework and .NET team) [made at the aspnet/Announcements github
repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/256):

> A very common issue we see when looking at user LINQ queries is the use of Include() where it is unnecessary and cannot be honored. The typical pattern usually looks something like this:
>
> ```
> var pids = context.Orders
>     .Include(o => o.Product)
>     .Where(o => o.Product.Name == "Baked Beans")
>     .Select(o =>o.ProductId)
>     .ToList();
> ```
>
> One might assume that the Include operation here is required because of the reference to the Product navigation property in the Where and Select operations. However, in EF Core, these two things are orthogonal: Include controls which navigation properties are loaded in entities returned in the final results, and our LINQ translator can directly translate expressions involving navigation properties.

Answer (score 5):

If you `Include` a child, it is loaded as part of the original query, which makes it larger.

If you don't `Include` or reference the child in some other way in the query, the initial resultset is smaller, but each child you later reference will lazy load through a new request to the database.

If you loop through 1000 users in one request and then ask for their 10 photos each, you will make 1001 database requests if you don't `Include` the child...

Also, lazy loading requires the context hasn't been disposed. Always an unpleasant surprise when you pass an Entity to a view for UI rendering for example.

**update**
Try this for example and see it fail:

```
var book = await context.Books.First();
var theme = book.Theme;
```

Then try this:

```
var book = await context.Books.Include(b => b.Theme).First();
var theme = book.Theme;
```

Comment: I am using Entity Framework Core which does not have Lazy Loading (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3312) ... Inf fact I never use Lazy Loading ... So am I missing something in my code or in your explanation?

Comment: I missed you use Core. Still, your query references the Themes directly, so the data gets loaded. If you didnt ref. Theme in the query but then tried to access the navigation propery of the materialized entities, you would need Include in the query.

Comment: Yes, I get that part. Can you check my update? If a column is not in the projection will still be loaded into memory if I use Include? Do you know?

Comment: I see your worry now :) You shouldnt be getting those columns since you dont materialize the entities, but why don't you log the generated sql and look for yourself?

Comment: Yes, I will ... I usually use Glimpse or Console. I was just considering strange that Include was not needed if using a projection so I got confused.

Comment: all columns in the referenced entries will be loaded unless projected away. Include is only used to express left join in method syntax (and it also only changes this part in the created SQL query). Include IS needed if you use a projection and don't want an additional round trip to the database - that is, if the entry is still part of the context, otherwise you'll run into an exception.